# Is it possible to export multiple excel files from a table using toad?

Tags: oracle, toad

I have a table with over 200,000 records in it which needs to be reviewed.  I'd like to divide the table up into excel sheets of around 5000 records each to give to reviewers who do not have access to the database.  What is the best way to go about doing this in Toad?  Thank you.

Comment: Export full data into one worksheet, than split it to many sheets by using VBA

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. But isn't a database with a power query language a great tool for reviewing data? What is going to be the results of the review?

Comment: export as csv, then use split command in linux or similar split tool for Windows (many out there)

Answer (score 0):

This link https://community.oracle.com/thread/2544010?tstart=0 has a wonderful function that converts a query to an Excel spread sheet. I have successfully used this on several occasions. Here is an admittedly weak example:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
        write_query_to_excel (
            p_sql           => 'select * from dual'
          , p_directory     => 'MYDIR'
          , p_filename      => 'data_from_dual'
          , p_worksheetname => 'one'
        )
    );
END;
```

Remember that p_directory is an Oracle directory object that points to the file system, not a file system directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 12.2, then in SQLPlus you can simply do

```
set markup csv on
spool <filename>

select blah... from table

spool off
```